# Adding more than one value to a Key in a Dictionary with Tuple Values

Tags: c#, dictionary, tuples

So, I'm writing a program that handles taxes.
I've got a Dictionary that is set up as following:

```
static Dictionary<Commodity, Tuple<DateTime, double>> _TaxRates = new Dictionary<Commodity, Tuple<DateTime, double>>();
```

*Commodity is an Enum* that handles different tax areas (Food, Alcohol, Transport etc.).
Now, I want to add a new tax rate, and the datetime that the tax rate was added.

So for instance, the Tax rate for Alcohol might have been 0,25% at 17:00, but at 17:25 it was 0,50% instead.

```
_TaxRates [commodity].Add(new Tuple<DateTime, double>(DateTime.Now, rate));
```

This gives me an error.

```
_TaxRates[commodity] =  Tuple.Create(DateTime.Now, rate);
```

And this seems to just overwrite the old value, meaning Alcohol has only ever had one Tax rate. Any helps or tips greatly appreciated.

"Full code" below:

```
            static Dictionary<Commodity, Tuple<DateTime, double>> _TaxRates= new Dictionary<Commodity, Tuple<DateTime, double>>();
        public void SetCustomTaxRate(Commodity commodity, double rate)
        {
            _TaxRates[commodity].Add(new Tuple<DateTime, double>(DateTime.Now, rate));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `Tuple` only stores a single set of values. You want a `Dictionary<Commodity, List<Tuple<DateTime, double>>` instead.

```
private static readonly Dictionary<Commodity, List<Tuple<DateTime, double>> _TaxRates = new();

public void SetCustomTaxRate(Commodity commodity, double rate)
{
    if (!_TaxRates.TryGetValue(commodity, out var list))
    {
        list = new List<Tuple<DateTime, double>>();
        _TaxRates[commodity] = list;
    }
    
    list.Add(new Tuple<DateTime, double>(DateTime.Now, rate));
}
```

**NB:** Depending on your target framework, you may want to use a `ValueTuple` instead.
[Tuple types - C# reference | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/value-tuples)

**NB2:** The code is not thread-safe. You should either lock the field, or use a `ConcurrentDictionary<Commodity, List<(DateTime, double)>>` instead.

**NB3:** Since you're using `DateTime.Now`, you should watch out for daylight savings time issues. Consider using `DateTime.UtcNow` or switching to `DateTimeOffset` instead.

Comment: Thank you for answer! No wonder i couldn't save multiple values then with my tuple hehe.

Comment: A dictionary of lists of tuples, that makes my head hurt. Just make a proper class, so much easier to read.

Comment: @DavidG I would generally agree, especially if the type was exposed outside of the class. Otherwise, either a `ValueTuple` with named values (`List<(DateTime date, double rate)>` or a `record` would be a better choice than the older `Tuple<DateTime, double>`.

Comment: Let's be real, this is for an assignment. No way this would ever be used in a real life scenario.